# CS50 Fuel Gauge what causes inputs like '1.5/3' results in reprompt?

Tags: python, exception, cs50

I had passed all the tests but I'm just curious about how do inputs like '1.5/3' or '2.5/5' gets reprompt?
Below is the code:

```
def main():
    percentage = -1
    while percentage == -1:
        fraction = input('Fraction: ')
        percentage = convert(fraction)
    return_val = gauge(percentage)
    print(return_val)


def convert(fraction):
    try:
        #if / not in fraction, not enough values to unpack so ValueError
        numerator, denominator = fraction.split('/')
        numerator = int(numerator)
        denominator = int(denominator)
        if numerator <= denominator and denominator != 0:
            return round((numerator/denominator)*100)
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        return -1


def gauge(percentage):
    if percentage <= 1:
        return 'E'
    elif percentage >= 99:
        return 'F'
    else:
        return f'{percentage}%'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

question link :[question](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/fuel/)

Comment: `1.5` can't be cast to an `int()`.

Comment: But when i tried to do something e.g. x = int(1.5) print(x) it prints out a 1

Comment: Try `int("1.5")` - you get strings from `input`...

Comment: So you can only use int() on a float to convert it into an integer or on a string which represents an integer right? Whereas using int() on a string which represents a float results in an error?

Comment: That's it, yes. ([See the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int))

Answer (score 0):

The problem requirements specify that the numerator and denominator are integers. And if you try to typecast float values to integers, python will throw an exception. To cover the case of decimal values for numerator and denominator, we need to convert them into floats and then divide. The final value would be a float, which was going to be the case with integers anyway, and you have to convert it back to integer.

See the code below:

```
def main():
    f = get_fraction_value('Fraction: ')
    if f >= 99:
        print('F')
    elif f <= 1:
        print('E')
    else:
        print(f'{f}%')

def get_fraction_value(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            n,d = input(prompt).split('/')
            result = 100*float(n)/float(d)
            if result>100:
                raise ValueError 
            else: 
                return int(result) 
    
        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
            pass
        
main()
```